# Duplicate Documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch, duplicates

I am relatively new to Elasticsearch and been using my personal twitter data as an example to use. I did not do any special mapping at the beginning and am using the default twitter mapping, and have created a front-end system to display my tweets with no issue. The problem that I want to remove is that I want to be able to remove any duplicate tweets using the "text" field.

Comment: which es version are you using? would it be possible for you to change /extend your mapping? a [more like this query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) could work for you

Comment: I am using Version 1.1.2 of ES

Comment: Can you provide more information here. Like is it the exact text match ?